# Finding Roots Numerically That Are Closely Located

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, algorithms, roots, numerical-calculus

I have a function $$f(x)=m(\sin^2(\frac{n}{x}\pi)+\sin^2(x \pi))-k$$ where $m,n$ and $k$ are integers. I also have an interval $[a,b]$ where two roots must lie in. These root are simple (aka has a multiplicity of 1 and goes through the x-axis). These roots are close together, so that $|r_1-r_2|<2$. $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ need not to 
have opposite signs nor does $a$ or $b$ be close to any of the roots. So, my question is are there some root-finding algorithms or variants of the popular algorithms (Newton's, Secant, etc.) that can find one of the roots.

**EDIT:** I am interested in the algorithms independent of their programming (though if you want to give a coded example, it would be optimal to do it in Python 3)

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that you want to do this in some sort of programming language?  Have you decided what programming language to use?

Comment: Some of them are listed in http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html. There are a lot of options - let me know which programming language you intend to use.

Comment: @Axion004: Perhaps the OP is interested in root-finding algorithms independent of the programming language used to implement them? That seems quite possible to me, given the algorithms mentioned in the post, but perhaps the OP could clarify.

Comment: @LeeMosher You are right. I just want to know the algorithms themselves.

Comment: @Axion004 I took a look at your site and it seems that to be guaranteed you must either a). Have two points where $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are oppposite signs, which I said would not always be the case or b). $a$ or $b$ is close to the root, which again I said, would not always be true.

Comment: I see, I need to look at specific methods later tonight. This doesn't answer the question but is useful information that I found on Google: http://www.math.niu.edu/~dattab/MATH435.2013/ROOT_FINDING.pdf

Comment: @Axion004 Wouldn't you know but I found the same result about 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I'm not sure how much good this will do, but the first thing I'd try is rewriting $[a,b]$ as $[c-d,c+d]$ with $0\lt d\lt c$ (this assumes $a$ and $b$ both have the same sign, which may not be the case), and then $x=c(1+u)$ with $|u|\le|d/c|\lt1$.

Comment: @BarryCipra How would I go from there given that $a$ and $b$ are the same sign and i calculated $x_1$?

Comment: @QuoteDave, what do you mean by "i calculated $x_1$"? Does that mean you've found one of the two roots in $[a,b]$?

Comment: @BarryCipra No, I meant I calculated your $x=c(1+u)$. I assumed it would be the first of many iterations, hence why I called it $x_1$. Sorry if this caused confusion.

Comment: @QuoteDave, thanks for the clarification. As I said, I'm not sure the change of variables I'm suggesting will do any good, but it's what occurred to me to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method I would use in school, when Newton's method would fail, is to use Newton's method EXCEPT divide f(x) by a sufficiently large number instead of dividing by the derivative. With this method, a program can run through millions of iterations quickly and still get the answer even if you set the denominator = +-1,000,000. It's sorta like setting the derivative equal to +-1,000,000 no matter what.
Find one root by setting the lower bound negative and the derivative -1,000,000,
Then find the other root by setting the upper bound positive and the derivative as 1,000,000.
Use this formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method

Comment: This is interesting, why would this work? Also, in relation to $m$, how big should the denominator be? For example, let $m=10^6$. How big should the denominator be?

Comment: I never had a way to determine what m should be. I just chose a number that was "sufficiently large" meaning that I was sure that the derivative at the root was significantly smaller. I guess one way you could have the computer find a sufficiently large number would be to sweep through the values around the root. For example:

Comment: For example what? You never finished.